# How to upgrade RAM of MacBook Pro 15-inch, Mid 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I want to upgrade my MacBook Pro 15-inch, Mid 2012. It has now 8 GB of RAM. I want to upgrade it to 16 GB.

Any suggestion on how to do this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've removed the shopping recommendation part of the question, see the [FAQ] for why such questions are usually off-topic.

Comment: is this a retina or non retina model? The non-retina model can be upgraded to 16GB, the retina model cannot be upgraded at all.

Comment: non-retina model

Answer (score 1):

macsales.com aka OWC is a fantastic website for buying RAM. I purchased 16 gb for my late 2011 model with no problems. Order the RAM amount that you want, then when the ram arrives you must unscrew the back cover of your macbook and find the RAM to remove, which you will then replace with the RAM you bought. I highly suggest watching a YouTube video on the correct procedure to do this, as it is virtually impossible to describe the process in words. Search on YouTube: installing RAM MacBook Pro. Good luck!

Comment: Even though some say that your computer can only be upgraded to a certain amount of RAM, many have found that it can be upgraded to 16 gigabytes with no problems, as I did with my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions directly from the Apple Support Site ([link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165)):

> **Step 1: Remove the bottom case**
>
> 1. Shut down your MacBook Pro. Disconnect the power adapter, Ethernet cable, USB cables, security lock, and any other cables connected to
>      the MacBook Pro to prevent damaging the computer.
> 2. Turn over your MacBook Pro and remove the ten (10) screws that secure the bottom case. Because the screws are different lengths, note
>      the screw lengths and locations so you can replace the screws
>      correctly. Put them aside in a safe place. Lift off the case and place
>      it to the side.
> 3. Touch a metal surface inside the computer to discharge any static electricity from your body.
>
> **Step 2: Remove existing memory (if present)**
>
> 1. Push the levers on the sides of the memory module in an outward direction to release the module from the memory card slot. The memory
>      pops up at an angle. Before removing it, make sure you find the
>      half-circle notches. If you don’t, try pressing the levers outward
>      again.
> 2. Hold the memory module by its notches and remove it from the slot.
> 3. Remove the other memory module.
>
> **Step 3: Install memory**
>
> 1. Align the notch on the gold edge of the module with the notch in the lower memory slot.
> 2. Tilt the card and push the memory into the slot.
> 3. Use two fingers with firm, even pressure to push down on the memory module. There should be a click when you insert the memory
>      correctly.
> 4. Repeat this procedure to install an additional memory module in the top slot. Press down on the module to make sure it is level.
>
> **Step 4: Replace the bottom case** Replace and tighten the ten screws you removed earlier, making sure to put the different length screws in
>   their proper locations.

If you prefer a more visual approach, this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNBWKx29uKY) (one of many I found) also shows how to perform the upgrade on a non-Retina MacBook Pro (mid-2012).